# CollectionView method didDeselectItemAt not work

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a trouble with method "didDeselectItemAt" in collection view.
App: i have a collection with cells(see screenshot). User can to highlight only one cell.

when the user clicks on one cell, it is highlighted. when he click on another one, another one is selected, and the previous one becomes normal.

and when I select, for example, the first cell, and then the last one, the first one remains selected.
empirically, I found out that this problem. happens when, after the first one, I click on a cell that is out of view while clicking on the first one (you need to scroll)

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == albumsCollectionView {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? AlbumCollectionCell else { return }
        cell.isCellSelected()
        presenter?.didChooseAlbum(with: indexPath.row) {
            self.picturesCollectionView.reloadData()
        }}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == albumsCollectionView {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? AlbumCollectionCell else { return }
        cell.isCellDeselected()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `cellForItem(at:)` returns nil if the cell is not visible is iOS15-. What's the value of `allowsMultipleSelection`? You might want to call the `isCellSelected` inside `setSelected(_:animated:)` to change the color instead.

Comment: The problem is not with `didDeselectItemAt` ... the problem is that you are calling a function in your cell to track its "selected state" instead of tracking the selected state in your data source.

Comment: hello, Larme. Where i have to  call setSelected(_:animated:) ?

Comment: @Latynskii - is the "selected" state only the background color?

Comment: @DonMag  about this collection - yes, but bellow i have another collection with pictures from selected album

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DonMag mentioned in the comment, you have to track selected state in your data source. Here are the steps.

As you are showing some data in cell, you can make a model for it.

```
struct Album {
    let name: String
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

In `AlbumCollectionCell` add `Album` type variable. And override the `isSelected` property of `UICollectionViewCell`

```
class AlbumCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var album: Album? {
        didSet {
            guard let album = album else { return }

            if shoe.isSelected {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            }
            else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            }
            
           self.albumLabel.textColor = .white
           self.albumLabel.text = album.name
        }
    }
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            }
            else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `UIViewController`, create an array of `Album` type which holds the data of cells. You may assign the data in `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
var albums = [Album]()
```

Set `allowsSelection` property of `UICollectionView` to `true`.

```
collectionView.allowsSelection = true
```

In `cellForItem` method pass the `Album` data to cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AlbumCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? AlbumCollectionCell {
        cell.album = albums[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Modify didSelectItem method like below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    albums[indexPath.item].isSelected = true
}
```

And override `didDeselectItemAt` method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    albums[indexPath.item].isSelected = false
}
```

Comment: thank for so huge an answer! could you write me about "shoe". What is is?

Comment: It’s a mistake. I wrote the answer by taking code from one of my projects. I have updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @MBT I think `collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first` will do the better case there is only one cell can be selected. To add a model just for tracking IndexPath of one selected cell is a bad idea.

Comment: @MBT it's work, but i just used isSelecred and DidSet. Thank you! A have one more question. how to make it so that when opening the screen with a collection, a certain cell is already selected?

Comment: @Latynskii you can select an item in `viewDidLoad()` method after setting up the collectionView like `let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 5, section: 0)
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)`

Comment: @MBT i tried this and unfortunately do not work, code:
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        albumsCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)

Comment: Could you please try it in `viewDidLayoutSubViews()` method? Hopefully, it will work.

Comment: @MBT oh sorry, now it is work. Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to **persist** the selection - that is, if you want to save it and restore the last selection between app uses, or if you're navigating away and you want to restore it when navigating again to that controller - then you need to track it with your data source.

However, if you're not concerned with persistence, you can let the collection view handle it.

In your cell class, override `isSelected`:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .systemOrange : .systemGreen
    }
}
```

Now, you don't need any "cell appearance" code in `didSelectItemAt` or in `didDeselectItemAt` ... the collection view will manage the selected state.

Here's a quick, complete example...

**Custom Cell class**

```
class LabelCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label = UILabel()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
        ])
        contentView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    }
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .systemOrange : .systemGreen
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Controller class**

```
class SelColViewVC: UIViewController {
    
    var albumsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let myData: [String] = [
        "Favorites",
        "Recents",
        "Recently Added",
        "Something Else",
        "Five",
        "Six",
        "Seven",
        "Eight",
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 50)
        albumsCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        albumsCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(albumsCollectionView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            albumsCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            albumsCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            albumsCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            albumsCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
        ])
        
        albumsCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 8.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 8.0)
        albumsCollectionView.register(LabelCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        albumsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        albumsCollectionView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
}
extension SelColViewVC: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LabelCollectionViewCell
        c.label.text = myData[indexPath.item]
        return c
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == albumsCollectionView {
            presenter?.didChooseAlbum(with: indexPath.item) {
                self.picturesCollectionView.reloadData()
            }}
        }
    }
}
```